# Is it possible to install encrypted Ubuntu 16.04.1 without GRUB on partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 16.04, encryption

I divided my disk to 2 partitions - 1st for Windows and 2nd for Ubuntu. I've finished Windows installation and now I'm trying to install Ubuntu and I stumbled upon problem:

1. It seems like it's not possible to do an encrypted installation when you're not installing on whole disk. Can I do it by installing without encryption and then turn the `/boot` and `/` partition to LUKS drives from live session?
2. I have other disk with Ubuntu 14.04 in my PC, so I don't need to install GRUB on this one. However, I don't see any option to install without GRUB. Or should I let it install (and overwrite) GRUB on Ubuntu 14.04 disk?

I'm installing in legacy mode.

Comment: Just install Grub to the MBR of the same drive, don't overwrite Grub in the MBR of the other drive. This way both drives don't depend on each other, booting to any of the both drives will be successful even if the other drive fails caused by what reason ever...

Comment: I'll do it, thanks. And what do you think about that encryption thing?

Comment: I never played around with encryption so I can't answer that, wait for someone else to give tips about that...